# Expected type 'array'. Found 'int'.intelephense(1006)

Tags: php, arrays, class, typeof

I've little problem with my PHP code.
Indeed i've an error when i do array_push or implode an array: " Expected type 'array'. Found 'int'.intelephense(1006) ".

I've declare the type of $element in contructor: i don't understand.

I provide you my code.

[My code in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufkV2.png)

(I can't paste my code: it is too long)

Thank for your help.
Cyril.

Comment: [edit] your question and paste your code as __text__.

Comment: And no, it's not too long.

Comment: Also read what __exactly__ `array_push` returns.

Comment: HI Cyril, please try to isolate the part of the code where your error originates. And welcome to Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`array_push`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) takes a reference of your array and the elements to be added.

Your code should look like this:

```php
array_push(&$this->element, $element);
```

or a more modern equivalent (and technically faster) variant:

```php
$this->element[] = $element;
```

The `[]` operator on an array adds the element.

Comment: Thank it's fixed !

The first solution feel be wrong (Visual studio return an error) but the second solution works !

Thank you :)